# TypeScript - class generic type is too narrow if extends something else, is not if does not extend anything

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have classes like `Item<T>` and `StrictItem<T extends Something>` . If I initialize the former like `Item('a')` it will be seen as `Item<string>`, while `StrictItem<'a'>` will be seen as `StrictItem<'a'>`.

1. Why does putting a constraint on the generic cause these differences? It doesn't seem to be related.
2. Is there a way to change the `StrictItem` definition, so `StrictItem('a')` would be `StrictItem<string>`, while still preserving the constraint on the generic?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoBs6gPICMBWECYAPACoB8yA3sgNqgAmEAHgFzIDOYUoA5sgC6HMgF8AUOLABPAA4oAkpAC2ANTjoArigC845MlwB7I+ghwQyAD77kITctzRrt7rxACbBpRDUbtdIIuBrQMIMzsXDz8Qhw+flooosF2mujoANySCJicnMjx5FTUtgayvABucJDIVYkiWQYGCEYgbprERlAAFHXaIgCUNKVNBmAAFsCcAHR9urX+EI1NEqOymrjowAhcEGC9i4PDo6MTU7OLyDoLicsGEhLiAPRPyGST+a0o62D5UBBubZgYCtT6WCYoPgQEDQbbiHJwPLIADK0WIhTIyFYkHC+Xi6kSVGx0MYeJURWGjxeyAAjNNkAB1cbSZCMIwA5AQrFQKBdXbQ5CgQUqABMrPZ+RARjAyCMCAQmigyHG0AgAH5xGYZcAVDSrnYIAB3AoqboAcjgZoGWR1vjpnD25twVptuumDv2AAZrZJqSL6QBhCwotFgeKsiAwUA6kGWJzIZRGRjAKMQRicoyC5SyLbEdAs0AwZxwBNdCDPV5QmFQDScuQoc2AjxWwXgj7IBCIhuGnXjIyaGWaTgxCwsmTyZAwPlkAYa6nYJVTLEsHPbHX5iNRkAxLnjlBGGDIWSIh3puaclWykAbw1wFndB0oW3KADMs81e2FvjF1xhxtRvDoqaFouuIz7+h6TqgR+2oqC++p-iGgFhsBlrIIiUTuHwPrPi+7qOmazrWkAA)

```
interface PlainObject<T> { [index: string ]: T}

type ItemValue =
  boolean |
  number |
  string |
  ItemValue[] |
  { [index: string ]: ItemValue } |
  null;

class Item<T> {
    private value: T;
    constructor(value: T) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public set(value: T) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

// This one puts restrictions on the generic
class StrictItem<T extends ItemValue> extends Item<T> {
}

// 1. Why does the error seen in item2 does not occur here?
let item1 = new Item('a');
item1.set('b');
item1.set(0); // error

// 1. Can StrictItem definition be modified to implictly infer a more
// general type ('string') in this case (without using any type for T)?
// Or is explicitly defining the type of passed value the only way (see item3)?
let item2 = new StrictItem('a');
item2.set('b'); // error

let item3 = new StrictItem('a' as string);
item3.set('b');
```

Comment: You can use `new StrictItem<string>('a')`

Answer (score 3):

> *Why does putting a constraint on the generic cause these differences? It doesn't seem to be related.*

I believe that when you do `<T>` you tell the compiler, "just use whatever would normally be inferred. And in `let foo = 'bar'`, `foo` is inferred as `string`. And without extra notation, this makes sense as a default.

However, `<T extends ItemValue>` says something slightly different. This tells the compiler "T is a type that extends ItemValue, meaning that it may be a more specific subtype." In this case, it will infer the most specific type that it can.

So if you constrain a generic, you should expect it to be a super specific type. And usually, this is what you want.

---

> Is there a way to change the StrictItem definition, so `StrictItem('a')` would be `StrictItem<string>`, while still preserving the constraint on the generic?

Not that I know of. But this usually isn't actually a problem. It's hard to advise a course of action from your contrived example, but typically you're not actually hardcoding a string literal into a type like this. Instead the data is probably coming from some other data source, function, or variable.

In that case you can simply pass it a variable typed as `string` and it works like you expect.

```
let item4Data = getSomeString() // returns string
let item4 = new StrictItem(item4Data) // StrictItem<string>
```

---

And if you really do just want to pass in a literal, you can always pass in a type argument explicitly when you use the type. This is type safe because the type of the argument is checked against the type you provide.

```
let item5 = new StrictItem<string>('a')
item5.set('b') // works

let item6 = new StrictItem<string>(123) // type error
```

Comment: Using `StrictItem<string>('a')` seems to be the most elegant solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a solution:

```js
interface PlainObject<T> { [index: string]: T }

type ItemValue =
    | boolean
    | number
    | string
    | ItemValue[]
    | { [index: string]: ItemValue }
    | null;

class Item<T> {
    private value: T;
    constructor(value: T) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public set(value: T) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

type Infer<T> = T extends infer R ? R : never

// This one puts restrictions on the generic
class StrictItem<T extends ItemValue> extends Item<Infer<T>> { }

let item2 = new StrictItem('a');
item2.set('b'); // ok
```

You can just use `infer` to get the more general type and wrap it

**UPDATE**
As alternative solution, U can add second generic parameter with default value:

```js
interface PlainObject<T> { [index: string]: T }

type ItemValue =
    | boolean
    | number
    | string
    | ItemValue[]
    | { [index: string]: ItemValue }
    | null;

class Item<T> {
    private value: T;
    constructor(value: T) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public set(value: T) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

type Infer<T> = T extends infer R ? R & ItemValue : never

// This one puts restrictions on the generic
class StrictItem<T, R = Infer<T>> extends Item<R> { }

let item2 = new StrictItem('a');
item2.set('2'); // ok
```

Comment: That wouldn't work. It seems like the generic type is lost and `item2` is `StrictItem<ItemValue>` rather than `StrictItem<string>`. So for example, `item2.set(1);` wouldn't give an error either.  I think I will be fine initializing the class like `new StrictItem<string>('a')` like you suggested earlier in the comment. I was not aware of this syntax when I posted the question.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate it. Nevertheless, I settled for using `new StrictItem<string>('a')`

Comment: @MaciejKrawczyk spoko )